# Can I use Spark AR export in Swift ? “.arexport”

Tags: swift, spark-ar-studio

Can I use the file I exported with `Spark AR` on my own application in `Swift` or is there an alternative application for this? I just want to know how to do this job? How was the popular `GTA effect` done? I've always wondered about this subject. I just want to learn. Please do not give negative votes. If I asked the wrong question, I can correct it.